# Number of disjoint region of the plane

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

$10$ parabolas are drawn in a plane. Any two parabolas intersect in $2$ real and distinct point and  no three parabolas are concurrent. Find total number of disjoint region of the plane are.

Could someone tell me how to approach this question. I am not able to initiate it.

Comment: The solution depends on the position of the parabolas. For example  two parabolas can have their tops facing opposite directions giving five regions, but when the face the same direction we have only four regions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the best way to approach this would be to try counting it:

1. If we draw just 1 parabola, we can see that it divides the plane into 2 regions:

[image]

2. Drawing another parabola we get 5 regions (3 more)

[image]

3. Drawing another one, 3 parabolae give us 10 regions (5 more)

[image]

4. Drawing 4 parabolae give us 17 regions, (7 more)

[image]

So, $1$ parabola divides the plane into $2$ regions

$2$ parabolae, divide the plane into $(2 + 3)$ regions

$3$ parabolae, divide the plane into $(2 + 3 + 5)$ regions

$4$ parabolae, divide the plane into $(2 + 3 + 5 + 7)$ regions

by this pattern,

10 parabolae should divide the plane into $(2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + .. + 19)$ regions, or **101 regions**.